# Can a javascript file call a function defined in the main html file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to get this to work. I am including a javascript file with functions in it, but one of the functions in the file I want to be defined inside the main HTML file, not the javascript file. This isn't working however.

Here's what I want:

```
//testFile.js
$(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    var Scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var Width = $(window).width();
    var Height = $(window).height();
    var Offset;

    doParallax();
});

function Parallax(Obj, /*OffX, OffY,*/ ModifierX, ModifierY, Wait) {
    var ScrollT = $(window).scrollTop();
    var ScrollL = $(window).scrollLeft();
    var OffsetY = ScrollT - $(Obj).data("InitialTopOffset");
    var OffsetX = ScrollL - $(Obj).data("InitialLeftOffset");
    var SpeedX = OffsetX*ModifierX + XOff;
    var SpeedY = OffsetY*ModifierY + YOff;

    if (Wait) {
        if (ScrollT >= $(Obj).data("InitialTopOffset")) {
            $(Obj).stop(true, false).css( "background-position",  (ScrollL+SpeedX) + "px " + (-OffsetY-SpeedY) + "px", 50, "linear");
        }
    }
    else {
        $(Obj).stop(true, false).css( "background-position",  (ScrollL+SpeedX) + "px " + (-OffsetY-SpeedY) + "px", 50, "linear");
    }
}
});
```

//

```
//main HTML file
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function doParallax() {
   XOff = ( $(window).width() - ( $(window).width()*0.9 ) ) / 2;
   Parallax(".parallax3", 0, -0.55, true);
}
</script>
<script src="testFile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

I haven't been able to find anything from doing google searches or from searching on Stack Exchange. But assuming that it isn't working means that I can't do this, but is there a way to achieve the desired result?

EDIT: Actual code examples

Comment: Put the script element (along with the JS) before the closing body tag. - Also, add the jquery script reference to your HTML.

Comment: Do you realize that you haven't included jQuery yet? I'd imagine _that_ could put a spanner in the works. ;)

Comment: I forgot to include the jquery here but it is included in my code. If I separate everything out into two script tags with the html javascript function first before another script that points to the js file, it still doesn't work.

Comment: So you mean `doSomething()` is not defined as the console speaks?

Comment: The console is actually now saying that Parallax() is not defined. Is that because it's in the document.ready function?

Comment: Put the Parallax() outside the `$(function(){})` block. You should not put inside the block.

Comment: So, problem solved?

Comment: You need to put your testFile.js script declaration ABOVE the other inline script. It's simply a matter of order here. Parallax should really be defined first and foremost as well as any other object constructors, then functions, then bindings of events to functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid:

```
<script src="testFile.js">
function somethingElse() {
   alert("Called");
}
</script>
```

A `script` tag either references a script ***or*** contains a script.  Not both.  Separate them into their own tags:

```
<script src="testFile.js"></script>
<script>
function somethingElse() {
   alert("Called");
}
</script>
```

(Of course, this is ignoring the fact that the contrived example never *calls* `doSomething()`, but I assume that's just an oversight in the example.)

Note also that there may be a scope issue depending on when you *call* this function.  If `doSomething()` is invoked before `somethingElse()` is in scope, that could be a problem.  You may be able to hoist it to the top of the current scope by defining it like this though:

```
var somethingElse = function() {
    alert("Called");
}
```

Not sure if that's even an issue here though, since the code in the question doesn't actually invoke any functions.

---

**Edit:** Since the question has drastically changed...

In a comment above you mention the problem:

> The console is actually now saying that Parallax() is not defined.

This is because that function exists only within the scope of the function you're using in the `document.ready` handler.  To simplify:

```
$(function () {
    // anything created here only exists here
});

// so you can't call it here
```

If you have functions which need to be invoked outside that scope, define them outside of that scope:

```
$(function () {
    // perform document ready handler actions here
});

var Parallax = function() {
    //...
}

var doParallax = function() {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I commented on this above, still doesn't work. yeah, it's just an oversight ;)

Comment: @RyanAndrews: Define "doesn't work".  Nothing in your code actually *does* anything, so what is the issue exactly?

Comment: @RyanAndrews Well maybe an example showing how you try to call the method inside the document ready would clear it up... I am sure the Developer console has errors.

Comment: In the actual code, I'm calling the function defined in the HTML file when a scroll event happens, so the function should get called. The function is also defined in it's own script block before the other js file is included. So the function is defined before it is called, but it doesn't get called. The console says the function is not defined.

Comment: So what is the error in the console? Are you sure your scroll event is actually being attached, show the actual code.

Comment: @RyanAndrews: Can you include code in the question which actually demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @RyanAndrews You should have point out that earlier! Consider what evolutionxbox said, in the very first comment.

Comment: And the actual code shows the actual problem. Calling a method in global context that is inside the document ready.

Comment: @RyanAndrews: Answer updated to reflect the modified question.

Comment: Suggested in the comment already